# Selecting nested values with a list inside a dict, when a value matches

Tags: ansible

Within the dict `hostvars[inventory_hostname]` I have multiple occurrences of the below, one per each server in the inventory.
The value I need to extract is `proxyServer.detail.name` *only when* the `proxyServer.datail.inbound_ip` matches a variable that is available to me.

Furthermore, my search cannot have `proxyServer` hardcoded as there are multiple types of servers and I must iterate through all of them - in order to find the match for my IP address, and then extract the corresponding "name".

```
                    "proxyServer": {
                        "commonName": "outbound",
                        "proxy.example.com": {
                            "ipaddress": "10.1.100.100"
                        },
                        "detail": [
                            {
                                "inbound_ip": "10.1.100.100",
                                "outbound_ip": "192.168.1.250",
                                "name": "proxy.local"
```

I've tried multiple variations of:

```
- debug:
  var: "item.key"
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].proxyServer.detail[0] }}"
    when: "'10.1.100.100' in item.value"
```

But when there is a match, I'm already "too deep" and cannot extract the `name` any more.

```
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "key": "internal_ip",
        "value": "10.1.100.100"
    },
    "item.key": "internal_ip"
}
```

My method will also not scale as I'm hardcoding `detail` so it will only match that one single dict, and nothing else in the data.

Any pointers would be welcome, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *json_query*. For example, the task below shall give you a list of selected "proxyServer" variables where "inbound_ip" is "10.1.100.100"

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        proxyServer_selected: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
               map('extract', hostvars, 'proxyServer')|list|
               json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        inbound_ip: "10.1.100.100"
        query: "[?detail[?inbound_ip == '{{ inbound_ip }}']]"
      run_once: true
```

Then, process the list and extract what you want.

---

Q: **"*Doesn't this depend on the fact that I must code in the 'proxyServer' value ?*"**

A: No. It does not. It's possible to iterate the values and concatenate the lists of the results. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vars_selected: "{{ vars_selected|default([]) +
                           [ansible_play_hosts_all|
                           map('extract', hostvars, item)|list|
                           json_query(query)] }}"
      vars:
        inbound_ip: "10.1.100.100"
        query: "[?detail[?inbound_ip == '{{ inbound_ip }}']]"
      run_once: true
      loop:
        - proxyServer
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. Doesn't this depend on the fact that I must code in the "proxyServer" value ? The proxyServer (and its siblings) are the list of dicts that I must iterate through. If that makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome. It's possible to iterate such a list. I've updated the answer. If you have another issue open a new question and make it [mre].

Comment: I may have something as well: `"{{  mydict['app']['detail']|selectattr('internal_ip', 'equalto', '10.1.1.100') |  map(attribute='name') | list  }}"` now all I need is for this to match anything on the "`internal_ip` key. something like match('^.*$) but I can't seem to regex on the key field, only on the value field.

Comment: There is a plethora of [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#tests) and 
 [Jinja tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests). But, still the same, from the comments it's difficult to guess what are you looking for. Open a new question and make it [mre], please.